# Wordpress Grid Post CSS Styling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i am still learning CSS and i need some help regarding styling buttons at the bottom left of a container.

I have created a blog website which displays all my post. However, these posts are not aligned when shown in the page. I know that they are not aligned due to the different number of letters in each post.

Hence i thought of using a static container (.fixed_post_container) of size 370x280 for all post. However, i have some trouble to align the buttons at the bottom left of the (.fixed_post_container).

I hope to achieve a rigid Grid layout, with buttons aligned to each other, no matter the number of text.

My website is https://dylogue.com/pulse/
[image]

The container class (.fixed_post_container).

The button class (.button_align_bottom).

Thank you

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your post.

Answer (score 1):

haha i fixed it!

```
.button_align_bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10;
}
```